# How can I have access to values in a table with values() or iteritems()

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-unittest

[image: image of sample table]

I have created a table containing header rows, header columns, column ids and row ids (the above picture is a very simple example of the table structure), and have used some methods of a specific class to convert the table to weighted flat cross-tab and pivot cross tab, etc. Now what I'm looking for is to test if the values in the table are float , so I've developed a unittest test suite. I have used Table.values(), or Table.iteritems(), but these two methods iterate over all the Table including the headers and ids which are all strings , therefor the test is failed. Does anyone have a better solution to iterate only the values of the table regardless of the labels in the table?

```
    row_ids=['g','p']
    col_ids=['r','c']
    values = { ('g','r'): 0.75, ('g','c'): 0.25, ('p','r'): 0.5, ('p','c'): 0.5, }
    header_row = { 'id':'forme', 'type':'string' }
    header_col = { 'id':'taille', 'type': 'string', }
```

What I'm looking for is to only read the values in the values dictionary, but with values() and items() the output is a tuple of key and value. That's why the test is failed.

Comment: I assume that you have created your own `Table` class? Can you show us the relevant code? An idea would be to seperate headers and actual data within this class.

Comment: Well yes, I used the methods in a table class created by my teacher, and the headers are separately introduced in a list whose items are the keys to another dictionary containing the values. This is a slice of the codes:row_ids=['g','p']
        col_ids=['r','c']

        values = {
            ('g','r'): 3,
            ('g','c'): 1,
            ('p','r'): 2,
            ('p','c'): 2,
            }

        header_row = {
            'id':'forme',
            'type':'string'
            }

        header_col = {
            'id':'taille',
            'type': 'string',
            }

Comment: The OP should clarify in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Yes you're right, I've edited the question. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: Can you override the `values` or `iteritems` methods of the `Table` class? Or you access the "internal" `values` variable directly: `objectOfTheTableClass.values.values()`.

Comment: The problem with         .values.values() is that it also reads the elements of the first line which are in fact the column ids. That's why the test is executed with failure. I want to get rid of the first line and the first column, and need a command iterate over the whole table except for the first line/column. I tried        values and         iteritems and it gives the same result.

Comment: Please add the definition of the `Table` class to your question. Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean you want to do this:

```
for k, v in values.iteritems():
    if k: # if k has a value indicating this is a header:
        continue  # skip it
    if not isinstance(v, float):
        print 'bad value: ', k, v
```

Comment: Is it possible to give arguments to iteritems()? For example iterate over the items except for the row_ids and col_ids

Comment: Just read the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems It's not possible.

Comment: I just tried your edited codes and it worked properly. Thank you indeed @tom-zych